# Error en la inicialización del sistema de configuración

Tags: c#, windows-forms

tengo este error que me sale en esta línea se asigna null

db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(CadenaConexion);

la CadenaConexion si trae datos

cabe mencionar que estoy migrando una aplicación que estaba con el famework 2 a una que ya esta hecha en el framework 4

el app.config es este:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="ColaboracionE.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="rutas" type="string"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Inte" connectionString="Server=DESAOPER;Database=eDocInteDB;User=usr_InteDB;Pwd=G0rd1t@5314;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="Prod" connectionString="Server=SRVECOM;Database=eDocProdDB;User=DboCorporativo;Pwd=Grabar" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Integracion" value="Inte"/>
    <add key="Produccion" value="Prod"/>
  </appSettings>
  <rutas>
    <add key="RutaArchivo" value="%RUTAARCHIVO%"/>
    <add key="Delimitador" value="
|"/>
    <add key="URLCSDSAT" value="ftp://ftp2.sat.gob.mx/agti_servicio_ftp/verifica_comprobante_ftp/CSD.txt"/>
    <add key="URLFOLSAT" value="ftp://ftp2.sat.gob.mx/agti_servicio_ftp/verifica_comprobante_ftp/FoliosCFD.txt"/>
  </rutas>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" publicKeyToken="8fb06cb64d019a17" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.10.0.0" newVersion="2.10.0.0" />
        <!--<assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.0.0.0" />-->
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <userSettings>
    <ColaboracionE.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="Password" serializeAs="String">
        <value />
      </setting>
    </ColaboracionE.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

todo esta en c#, no tengo experiencia en windows forms

saludos y gracias

Comment: podrias poner la linea de codigo donde asignas la variable CadenaConexion ?

Comment: CadenaConexion = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem)(cboAmbiente.Items[cboAmbiente.SelectedIndex])).Value;

Comment: estas seguro que el valor que asignas con el item del combo es un connection string valido ? pusiste un breakpoint en el codigo y pasaste el mouse sobre la variable para verificar que toma un valor correcto

Comment: si, se asigna Inte o Prod

Comment: ok gracias el error ya no aparece, fue un conflicto con <rutas> comenté ese código y ya no salió el error